# Does VML have an equivalent to SVG's marker element?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, raphael, vml

I'm working on a project which uses Raphael to render SVGs for Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, and VML for Internet Explorer.

Since Raphael doesn't have built-in support for SVG marker elements, I decided to write a plugin for it myself. I got the SVG side working no problem, but the VML docs aren't giving me any help in finding a good way to implement markers in VML.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

No. Otherwise it would be part of Raphaël.